# Google Maps Places search box: how to recalculate position of pac-container

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use Places search box from Google Maps Javascript API v3:

```
var searchField = $(".search-box").get(0);
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(searchField);
```

I use it in a mobile web app. When the device orientation gets changed, the page font size is being recalculated (as a part of our app logic), so the size and position of search-box get changed.

But width and position of the autocomplete box (.pac-container) gets recalculated BEFORE changing size of other page elements, and I have no control on method responsible for this recalculation.

Is there a way to get access to method that is responsible for .pac-container inline CSS? It is not listed in API documentation, and I couldn't find it in minificated sources of maps api.

Comment: I would trigger the `resize` event on the map. That should tell the map to recalculate positioning.

Comment: Thank you, Chad, you helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering window resize event with delay (to let our app to change the page size) did the trick:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(window, 'resize');
}, 500);
```

Then I figured out that the issue was caused by css `transition: all` property set on the parent container. Removing the transition solved the problem.

Comment: You should trigger the map resize `goog.events.trigger(map, 'resize')`. It's also triggered off of window resize so this is why it works. Also, I would not recommend using a timeout, but tying this to a specific event when your app changes sizes.

Comment: The thing is I do not have a map on this page, only searchbox, so there is no map object. I tried `google.maps.event.trigger(searchBox, 'resize')` but with no luck. Anyway, I figured out that the issue was caused by css 'transition: all' property set on parent container. Removal of transition solved the problem.

Comment: Ahh I missed the places search reference. This is probably the best you can do then.